# Regex - PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
<div\s*class="selectionDescription">(.*?)<\/div>
```

Which works with PHP perfectly. I am aware that javascript does not support the \s flag.

I have tried using the \g flag, however my pattern is not matched.

I am looking to match everything inside the div in the following string:

```
<div class="selectionDescription">Text to match</div>
```

I receive the following error in javascript:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 's'(…)
```

Comment: Javascript does support `\s`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 's'(…)

Comment: [Your pattern seems to work.](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0vN7/1) What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Why not use use the DOM and do something like `document.getElemementsByClassName('selectionDescription')`?  Where is this string coming from and why are you using a regex on it?

Comment: Can you show us your *actual* JavaScript code?  `\g` isn't a flag, btw, it's `/g`.  Are you confusing `\s` (match a whitespace character) with the `/s` flag (to make `.` match new lines) or `/g` ("match all")?

Comment: @CMS, `\s` isn't a flag. It's a character class.

Answer (score 2):

[Your pattern seems to work.](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0vN7/1)

`s` is not a flag, so if you are trying something like `new RegExp('<div\s*class="selectionDescription">(.*?)<\/div>', 's')` then yes, you would find an error.

You do not need to add any flags, except perhaps the `g` flag to capture this div many times. ([Check it out](https://regex101.com/r/rJ0vN7/2))

[Maybe check out a quick primer on Javascript's regular expressions?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

If you are spanning multiple lines, and you mean the `single line` mode that `s` provides, you can emulate that with `[\S\s]` or some other similar "all inclusive, all exclusive" style: `[\d\D]`, `[\W\w]`, etc.

That will allow it to span multiple lines and still match:

```
<div\s*class="selectionDescription">([\S\s]*?)<\/div>
```

You need to be wary of using lazy `*?` quantifiers, however. Take a look at https://regex101.com/r/xD2jV8/1 where the number of steps is 220.

If the content between `<div>` and `</div>` tags is very large, this becomes very computationally expensive, very fast.

While slightly less readable,

```
<div\s*class="selectionDescription">((?:[^<]+|<(?!\/div>))*)<\/div>
```

would do the same but within only [69 steps](https://regex101.com/r/xD2jV8/2).

And at that point, https://regex101.com/r/xD2jV8/3 slightly optimizes it further, but HTML really isn't the best way to handle things with HTML. jQuery could perform this quickly and much "safer": `$('div.selectionDescription').html()`

Of course, you may not have access to this at this point, but HTML is usually not the best thing to use for parsing HTML.